# Get current user's name and user id

Tags: c#, asp.net

I dont do aspx at all so trying to work out this simple task.

I see the following code in some cs files which guess gets the current user and i assume this is a standard method in asp but might be wrong:

CS:

```
User user = (User)Context.Items["CurrentUser"];
```

I have tried things like this from other posts on here but maybe this system is different or the setup is different? again i dont know.

```
var currentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
string username = currentUser.UserName; //** get UserName
Guid userID = currentUser.ProviderUserKey; //** get user ID
```

Does anyone know how i can get the Name and User ID of the current user based on what is written above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends on how you handle users in your website.

if you use the asp.net built in user management, then `User.Identity.Name` will get you the currently logged in username.

other stuff like `(User)Context.Items["CurrentUser"]` or `(User)Session["myUser"]` will get you the user which was saved in those places somewhere in your website.

you just need to start your way from the login page, and follow the functions to see how users are being handled in your website.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, im sure i can work it out from here :)

Comment: sure :) if you need more help let us know

Comment: I ended up using user.Guid; and it seemed to not break and bring data back, just hope its the right ID - is there anyway to output the ID some how so i can see what its using? in the aspx file maybe and doing a console.log of some sort. Thanks

Comment: `Response.Write("blablabla");` would just print it out on the page directly, for testing only of course. you could also set a up a label with `runat="server"` attribute and just print the guid to `myLabel.innerText;", or you could a attach a n alert to the page's scripts in runtime with the guid as the alert var. or of course you could put a break point and debug the website to see if it gets the correct value